# Difference between connect-flash in node.js and console.log?

Tags: node.js, express, console.log

From what I understand, both do server printouts. I tried using flash below and I only see the console printout.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('hi there!');
    req.flash('info', 'flash test');
    req.end();
});
```

What's flash used for and how should I be using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash messages are displayed to the user viewing your site. console.log displays on the console where server is running.

[connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) is a middleware to implement flash messages. Flash message is displayed on the user browser, next time the user views a page. The flash is typically used in combination with redirects, ensuring that message is available to the next page that is to be rendered. It is like a reminder for last page viewed.

```
//go to /flash page
app.get('/flash', function(req, res){
  req.flash('info', 'Hi there!')
  res.redirect('/');
});
//info message shown when user sees / home page
```